# UWP Microsoft Graph Subscription Notification URL response

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I raise a subscription request as below and the response is:

Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.

Ho do I do I send this response please in UWP?

```
var result = await request.AddAsync(
                            new Subscription
                            {
                                ChangeType = "created,updated",
                                NotificationUrl = "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/notificationClient",
                                Resource = "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
                                ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                                ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                            }
                            );
```

Ok, I think i need the webhook and the notificationClient, how/ where do i get these values?

Answer (score 0):

Graph webhooks are not possible on UWP, at this time streaming notifications should be used from the outlook 365 api.

Comment: Are webhooks still unsupported on UWP? I cannot find any samples. I am not even sure how a webhook would work since my app does not have a URL.